# Random records in asending order in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to retrive  records `randomely`  in `ascending`  order using `mysql` query.

## MySQL Query

```
SELECT id,name FROM tbl_filedesc1 ORDER BY id ASC,RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Comment: If you have a random order, what does ascending mean? If it is random, it is random and only ascending in some cases (namely the ones that are ascending by pure chance), if it is ascending, it is not random. You should probably clarify what you mean by an example.

Comment: Grammatical error